# Proof is looking too simple to be true $f^{*}$ is a homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ be Vector Spaces over $K$ and let $f$ be a homomorphism from $V$ to $W$. Proof that $f^{*}$ from $W^{*}$ to $V^{*}$ is a homomorphism where $f^{*}$ sends $g$ onto $g \circ f$

I argued in a straightforward manner. For  $f^{*}(\alpha_1g_1+\alpha_2 g_2)(v)$
we apply the map and find $(\alpha_1 g_1+\alpha_2 g_2)(f(v))$.

But this is nothing but $\alpha_1 g_1(f(v))+\alpha_2 g_2(f(v))$.

We apply the definition of $f$ backwards and find $\alpha_1 f^{*}(g_1)(v)+\alpha_2 f^{*} (g_2)(v)$.

This shows that $f^{*}$ is a homomorphism. Is this correct?

Comment: In Mathematics, when something looks simple, it's good evidence that it's right, not wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this one really is about that simple.

You could improve your proof a little with an introduction like "For any $g_1, g_2 \in W^{*}$, any $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in K$, and any $v \in V$,"

Comment: OK ty my teacher sometimes complains that I'm missing out lots of important steps, and also ty for the improvment tip